# Function Calling issue

Tags: swift

I have two methods with same name with different parameters

```
func setName(name : NSString , fileName : NSString , data : NSData , body : NSMutableData)
{
    //statement
}
func setName(name : NSString , value : NSString , body : NSMutableData)
{
    //statement
}
```

when I am calling this methods i get errors like...

```
if condition
{
    setName(paramKeysArray[cnt], fileName: "Photo.jpeg", data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image), body: body) //Error :missing argument in parameter #2 in call
}
else
{
    setName(paramKeysArray[cnt], value: paramDic.objectForKey(paramKeysArray[cnt]), body: body) //Error : missing argument in parameter 'data' in call
}
```

why should it give this errors..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIImageJPEGRepresentation` is missing the second parameter. As it is declared:

```
func UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image: UIImage!, compressionQuality: CGFloat)
```

Also make sure all your parameters match the required types.